# Cannot repeat steps on how to get OAuth2.0 Access Token on Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, postman, token

On Postman, I can get new access token for OAuth2.0 by providing callback URL, auth URL and client ID.

[image: Postman OAuth2.0 Get New Access Token]

I want to break this task down on JMeter because I cannot find this function there. From my understanding, it is divided into authenticate -> authorise -> call back.

- Authenticate

  - URL = https://xxxxx/login
  - Result = Authorising URL
- Authorise

  - URL = https://xxxxx/oauth/authorize?client_id=mmm&redirect_uri=https://yyyyy/auth/callback&response_type=code
  - Result = code (e.g. zzz)
- Call back

  - URL = https://yyyyy/auth/callback?code=zzz
  - Result = token

As I used **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** on JMeter, I got the three actions mentioned above. When I reran them, it told me this error on **Authenticate** part: `<oauth><error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description><error>unauthorized</error></oauth>`.

To make sure that it was not about the program I use, I did it on Postman and found this error as well.
[image]

I wonder how I can break **OAuth2.0 Get New Access Token** feature into basic API settings in order to get access token on Postman or JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, I found that Postman's **OAuth 2.0 Get New Access Token** popped up a login page of targeted URL where I needed to fill in the username and the password so that the token could be obtained.

As I tried breaking down APIs required for this login, it required GET of that https://yyyyy and POST of that https://xxxxx/login. Click Send for POST, with username and password contained in form-data, then click Send for GET. The GET response would contain such the token.

However, just putting the aforementioned GET and POST APIs into one thread group did not work on JMeter. As I used **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** to no avail, I went with **BlazeMeter** and realised that it was using **Transaction Controller** containing 1) GET of https://yyyyy 2) POST of https://xxxxx/login. With these two arranged top-down, the job would be successful. The token was contained in the response of 2).

For now, this has been my discovery which answers my question.
Try BlazeMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' compare these tools:

- Postman is an [Electron application](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/postman), it's basically a heavily customised [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) web browser + [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- According to [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) main page

  > **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

If you can obtain the token using Postman you can just add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to your JMeter Test plan and configure it to send [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of `Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_FROM_POSTMAN` and JMeter should let you in.

Comment: That I fill in Bearer TOKEN is the way I don't want to do anymore because I have to inspect network element to obtain it manually. This is mainly about API settings, so you can forget about JMeter and test that on Postman only. Unless you mean what I see URL on Inspect Element cannot be directly copied to do on Postman, then we will eventually get token automatically.